# Stop consumption of message if it cannot be completed

Tags: masstransit

I'm new to mass transit and have a question regarding how I should solve a failure to consume a message. Given the below code I am consuming `INotificationRequestContract`'s. As you can see the code will break and not complete.

```
public class NotificationConsumerWorker : IConsumer<INotificationRequestContract>
{
    private readonly ILogger<NotificationConsumerWorker> _logger;
    private readonly INotificationCreator _notificationCreator;

    public NotificationConsumerWorker(ILogger<NotificationConsumerWorker> logger, INotificationCreator notificationCreator)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _notificationCreator = notificationCreator;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<INotificationRequestContract> context)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Horrible error");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // >>>>> insert code here to put message back for later consumption. <<<<<
            _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to consume message"); 
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I best handle a scenario such as this where the consumption fails? In my specific case this is likely to occur if a required external service is unavailable.

I can see two solutions.

- If there is a way to put the message back, or cancel the consumption so that it will be tried again.
- I could store it locally in a database and create my own re-try method to wrap this (but would prefer not to for sake of simplicity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [exceptions](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#redelivery) section of the documentation provides sufficient guidance for dealing with consumer exceptions.

There are two *retry* approaches, which can be used in combination:

1. Message Retry, which waits while the message is locked, in-process, for the next retry. Therefore, these should be short, to deal with transient issues.
2. Message Redelivery, which delays the message using either the broker delayed delivery, or a message scheduler, so that it is redelivered to the receive endpoint at some point in the future.

Once all retry/redelivery attempts are exhausted, the message is moved to the *_error* queue.